# React/Redux URL mismatch: When the array item number differs from the object id

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-redux

### Background

I am working on a final project for a course. I'm learning a lot as I go, but am still new to React/Redux.

I have an array of objects that I am rendering to a page. My home url is `/programs`. The user has the ability to click on a link to be taken to a details page. The link for that is `/program/<id of the program>`.

I have deleted some of the items in my database (Rails API), so the index number in the array differs from the item's actual id. [Here is an image to show an example of the discrepancy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkElJ.jpg)

Right now, that is messing up the `/program/<id of program>` display. I click on an item and I go to the wrong details page.

## Troubleshooting I've Done

To mitigate the issue, I've set up a filter inside my render to find the proper id. You can see it in my code below. It starts with `let program = this.props...`. However, now I cannot seem to access the `programId` and my card only partially renders. I have no values for `<Image>, <Card.Header>, <Card.Meta>,` or `<Card.Description>`.

I know for sure that the issue is with how I am accessing the keys in each object, I just don't know how to fix it.

***This paragraph added by request.***
[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgVAF.jpg) that shows the console.log values of `this.props.program`, `this.props.programs`, `this.props.match.params`. The match.id is fine, but the other two are undefined until the component mounts so that could be causing issues.

**Rendering a single program here**

```
render(){
      let program = this.props.program && this.props.programs.filter(program => program.id === this.props.match.params.id)[0]

      let programId = this.props.program && this.props.program.id

      let watchlistValue = this.props.program ? this.props.program.watchlist : null

      return(
          <Grid.Column>
            <Card as='div'>
              <Image src={program ? program.image : null} wrapped ui={false} />
              <Card.Content>
                <Card.Header>{program ? program.name: null}</Card.Header>
                <Card.Meta>
                  <span>{program ? program.network : null}</span>
                </Card.Meta>
                <Card.Description as='a' href={`/programs/${programId}`}>

                    More...

                </Card.Description>
              </Card.Content>
             </Card>
           </Grid.Column>
          )
```

### Thank you very much for your time and any advice you have!

Comment: can you console.log this.props.program, this.props.programs and the match.id? and add them to your question? I suspect this.props.program is undefined and the filter is never called.

Comment: What is the difference between `this.props.program.id` and `this.props.match.params.id`?

Comment: Why not pass `program` (Object) around instead of relying on the `programs` to figure out what should be displayed. This way you won't even run into the mismatch.  If there's no program selected, then clear it. Of course using redux for this is an over-kill.

Comment: @Domino987 Here they are. The match.id is fine, but the other two are undefined until the component mounts. [console.log image](https://imgur.com/7MC0lC3)

Comment: Can you expand the array with the programs in the image so we can see the structure of the objects?

Comment: @Domino987 How about [this](https://imgur.com/9pIwTeD)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to access `this.props.program` but it is undefined. You only have `this.props.programs` and that is why the filter function will never be executed.

Change it to this:

```
render(){
  const program = this.props.programs.find(program => program.id === this.props.match.params.id)

  const programId = program ? program.id : '';

  const watchlistValue = program ? program.watchlist : null

  return(
      <Grid.Column>
        <Card as='div'>
          <Image src={program ? program.image : null} wrapped ui={false} />
          <Card.Content>
            <Card.Header>{program ? program.name: null}</Card.Header>
            <Card.Meta>
              <span>{program ? program.network : null}</span>
            </Card.Meta>
            <Card.Description as='a' href={`/programs/${programId}`}>

                More...

            </Card.Description>
          </Card.Content>
         </Card>
       </Grid.Column>
      )
```

You have program only locally and it is not added to your props.

Comment: How strange. I still couldn't get it to work. I had to change program back to this `let program = this.props.program ? this.props.program : this.props.programs[this.props.match.params.id - 1]`

Comment: What is the error you are getting? This.props.program will always the undefined because you don't pass it to the component.

Comment: There's no error, it just renders a blank card [like this](https://imgur.com/a/XmCf8u6). My image, header, and meta aren't populating.

Comment: So if you use my approach, what is program right after the filter/? FYI, you can also use find. It works exactly like filter but returns the first object that matches instead of an array.

Comment: Yeah, find is what I needed. I was able to get it to work by changing my program variable to this: `let program = this.props.program ? this.props.program : this.props.programs.find(program => parseInt(program.id) === parseInt(this.props.match.params.id))`

Comment: that's great, do you pass program as a separate prop in certain cases?